# Sending mail through smtp and gettin error?

Tags: java, smtp, sendmail

This is my code. I am getting the following exception.

```
final String username = "mymail@gmail.com";
final String password = "mypass";

Properties props = new Properties();
props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");

Session session = Session.getInstance(props, new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
    protected javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
        return new javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
    }
});
try {
    Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
    message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("fazeen.ahmad93@gmail.com"));
    message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse("fazeenahmad1993@gmail.com"));
    message.setSubject("Testing subject");

    BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
    messageBodyPart.setText("test body");

    Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();
    multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
    messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
    message.setContent(multipart);

    Transport.send(message);
```

Exception I am getting:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.mail.MessagingException: 530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first. pl7sm1333988wic.4 - gsmtp
  at Test.main(Test.java:200)
       Caused by: javax.mail.MessagingException: 530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first. pl7sm1333988wic.4 - gsmtp
  at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.issueCommand(SMTPTransport.java:1020)
  at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.mailFrom(SMTPTransport.java:716)
  at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendMessage(SMTPTransport.java:388)
  at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:169)
  at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:98)
  at Test.main(Test.java:195)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing to add  to your properties the following fuse..

```
mail.smtp.starttls.required=true
```

Comment: i was using old version of **mail.jar** this was the reason

Answer (score 0):

Use this running code for sending mail

```
import java.util.Properties;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;

/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

/**
 *
 * @author xyz
 */
public class MailSend {
    public static void main (String [] args){
         String to="xyz@gmail.com";//change accordingly

//Get the session object
  Properties props = new Properties();
  props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
  props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
  props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class",
            "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
  props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
  props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");

  Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props,
   new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
   protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
   return new PasswordAuthentication("email_address","password");//change accordingly
   }
  });

//compose message
  try {
   MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
   message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("email_address"));//change accordingly
   message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,new InternetAddress(to));
   message.setSubject("Welcome!!");

    message.setText("Hiii buddy ");



   Transport.send(message);

   System.out.println("message sent successfully");

  } catch (MessagingException e) {throw new RuntimeException(e);}

 }
    }
```

if you have no smtp server on your machine then download it and run after downloading.

try this

Answer (score 0):

I was Using old version of **mail.jar** use this jar **mail-1.4.7.jar** and after that for authentication **To open Account Access : https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps (turn on)** this was the problem if using **google smtp**